# Vim pathogen and helptags autogeneration: errors

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have the following:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
silent execute pathogen#helptags()
```

But I keep getting an error, that I don't like:

> Error detected while processing function pathogen#helptags: line    4:
>   E154: Duplicate tag "BEFORE" in file
>   /Users/****/MacVim-snapshot-64/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles/doc/pyclewn.txt
>   E154: Duplicate tag "MUST" in file
>   /Users/****/MacVim-snapshot-64/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles/doc/pyclewn.txt

I like to have my vim startup completely without any errors, because errors are annoying. I'm confused as to why

> silent execute

isn't making the command not output errors; I want helptags to execute for all the other directories as well and not die on pyclewn.

So I even tried editing the pyclewn autoload source, where pathogen#helptags is defined in order to put

> silent helptags ...

in replacement. But even this doesn't make it silent. This might sound like a silly question, but I really like to have my helptags always fresh, and I don't like to see errors. Ideally, it should be fixed, but then I don't know if I should fix it and suggest it to pyclewn developers, or if I should just make the helptags command continue without hitch even after hitting a small bump. How can I make the error go away, without requesting a repository change from the maintainer of pyclewn?

Answer (score 3):

`silent` swallows regular output. use `silent!` to swallow errors.

Comment: thank you so much Tim. You are so helpful! But now that romainl pointed that out, I think it best that I fix the file and report the fix to the pyclewn developers :)

Answer (score 1):

We have different definitions of "perfectionist". As a perfectionist, I would fix the error instead of hiding it.

If you don't feel like fixing it yourself I'd advise you to report the issue to the author of the plugin so that he can fix it himself and make the fix available to every user.

*That* would be "perfectionist".

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version, pyclewn-1.10.py2, as of today (April 7, 2013) and
had the same error.  I edited my pyclewn.txt like following and the error is gone.

```
$> cd pyclewn-1.10.py2
$> diff runtime/doc/pyclewn.txt ~/.vim/doc/pyclewn.txt
541c541
< 'inferior-tty' variable *MUST* be set *BEFORE* the inferior is started.
---
> 'inferior-tty' variable MUST be set BEFORE the inferior is started.
741,742c741,742
<                     and the TERM environment variable; this command  *MUST* be
<                     issued *BEFORE* starting the inferior.
```

Also, I just found out that there's a fix from pyclewn developer already.
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3607476&group_id=212808&atid=1023202

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for telling me to do that romainl! I should have fixed this myself in the first place.

I found that by merely breaking that single tag in the file at line 541 by navigating to both *MUST* and *BEFORE* and doing :normal cwMUST  and :normal cwBEFORE, that I can get Helptags to run to completion. But this isn't perfect.

To understand what is happening, I read the help help-writing, and found that you should have unique targets, with identifiers that have *'s around them. To designate a target tag, use |'s around something.

So, |source| -> * dest *

At line 741 & 742, I think the MUST and BEFORE has both *'s and |'s on it, because helptags is complaining about it, and because I can jump from there to line 541. From 541 I can not jump to 741.

Long story short, the for this silly question, go to line 741 and replace the surrounding *'s with |'s. Helptags works to completion now.